# Difference between adb "install" command and "pm install" command?

Tags: android, adb, android-package-managers

What's the difference between installing an app using the `install` command and using the package manager's `pm install` command? Do they do the exact same job? Does one command actually call the other in the back?

```
adb install -r APK_FILE
adb shell pm install APK_FILE
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`adb install` is a command to run from a development host, which uploads a package somewhere temporary and then installs it.

`pm install` is a command to run locally on the device.

`adb` does indeed utilize the `pm` program on the device - see the source code at

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/adb/commandline.c

Comment: Updated link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/refs/heads/master/commandline.cpp

Comment: The reason this points at a specific revision is that the way things are implemented tends to change between versions, and "head" is not a specific version and so not a stable link eg, what is a .c file today might be a .cpp file next time around, or whatever.

Comment: So given that adb does utilize the `pm` program on the device, does that mean it should take all the same command-line options? The behavior I'm seeing is different. For example, `adb shell pm install` (on Android 10 device) rejects options like `--no-incremental` and `--wait` with an error such as "Unknown option --no-incremental." Whereas `adb install` gives no such error (but maybe ignores those options).