# What does pm install do, other than copy the apk to /data/app?

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-package-managers

What does pm install do, other than copy the apk to /data/app ?

It seems to be renaming apks to app-1.apk, app-2.apk at least. Why does it do that?

Is it ok to just copy the apk to /data/app, like we can do when installing system apps in /system/priv-app ?

Answer (score -1):

You seems to have the rooted phone. Hence you are able to see all this.

pm install just locally install the apk in device.  See this. 
[Difference between adb "install" command and "pm install" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685945/differenct-between-adb-install-command-and-pm-install-command)

Copy into data/apk is not allowed and is not the standard way to do it. 
Rather you have have apk installer application or use the adb instead.

regards
ashish

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. What does pm do other than copy the apk to /data/app ?

Comment: It install the apk in the android device or emulator.